# Getting redirected when I try to go to the quant Stack Exchange site

Tags: support

Someone recommended that I post my question on `quant.stachexchange.com`. Whenever I try to go to that site (I am not sure if the Stack Exchange site exists) I get redirected to something asking if I am a robot, then `www.clickvalidator.net`. Does this seem right? It seems like something weird is going on with DNS.

I was typing `quant.stackexhange.com`. Different URL, same problem.

Comment: We don't own and have no control over stackexhange.com (no "c" in "exchange"), so the best we can do is suggest you be careful when typing in the URL.

Comment: @AdamLear you ask too much :)

Comment: I hear ya. Life on the internet is tough these days. :)

Comment: @Adam I just ran into this when I typo'd (exact typo unknown, but I either missed the "c" or the "h"). The resulting site was suspicious to say the least. Loads of redirects, "offers", looked like it probably malware. I realise it's not _your_ site, but you did buy stacexchange.com - there must be some recourse to reclaim some other "typo" domains as criminals are blatantly taking advantage of your users!

Answer (score 3):

The address you have:

```
http://quant.stachexchange.com
                 ^
```

It shows an error, DNS address not found.

It should be:

```
    https://quant.stackexchange.com
                      ^
```

And the site loads perfectly.

If it is not a typo, check the extensions you have installed.

Comment: when I type out https. I get the the quantitative finance page. Without that I get redirected.

Comment: what happens? did you got the site? for me, even http is redirecting to https

Comment: I end up at a seemingly random site

Comment: can you confirm you just typed stackexchange not stachexchange

Comment: found it... someone else has stackexhange.com

Comment: The 'stach exchange site, while a great place to trade facial hair, has very little expertise when it comes to Quantitative Finance; you might want to check your DNS provider, @ford - I think they're hijacking your requests to serve you spam.